# Assign a single bit from STD_LOGIC_VECTOR to STD_LOGIC

Tags: vhdl

It seems like I have done this plenty of times, but for some reason today it just doesn't want to work.

I would like to assign the MSB of a 16-bit vector to a single-bit variable.

```
Din : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);

...

signal signBit : std_logic;

begin
    signBit <= Din(15 downto 15);
```

The error given is:

```
Type of signBit is incompatible with type of Din.
```

Yes I get it, vectors don't play nice with std_logic, but this is 1-bit, clearly denoted by (15 downto 15)

Comment: I assume there's a good reason you want to do this, and not just use `Din(15)`. Even though your slice is only 1 bit, the fact that you're accessing it with `downto` makes it an array, not the scalar you expect.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Din(15 downto 15);
```

is a std_logic_vector, 1 bit long

```
Din(15);
```

is one element of a std_logic_vector, i.e. a std_logic.

Comment: Ahh, I was confused. Thanks